# PHPDoc settings using interfaces in PhpStorm

Tags: interface, phpstorm, phpdoc, code-inspection

In my project I have an interface `IAction` which has PHPDoc for all functions. When I create a class which implements the interface I am getting an inspection error since there are methods that must be implemented. Hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> allows me to add method stubs:

[image: Inspection Fix]

Unfortunately the auto generated code copies over the PHPDoc like this:

[image: Unexpected PHPDoc]

Surprisingly, when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select which methods to implement, I can specifically select the documentation style:

[image: Option to select documentation type]

I was wondering whether there is any setting to choose how method stubs are documented when using the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> inspection fix. I would like to use `@inheritDoc` to prevent code duplication and conflicting documentation if I happen to change something later on.

Comment: I see that you have created the ticket anyway: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34386

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah, I noticed that since no one was able to answer where to find a specific feature it might be just not implemented. :)